# How to find the local maximum and minimum of $f(x)=x+\sin(2x)$ bounded by the interval $-\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{3}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Find the local maximum and minimum of $y=x+\sin(2x)$ between
> $-\frac{2\pi}{3}$  and $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

What I have done so far:

$f'(x) = 1+2\cos(2x)$  and $f''(x)=-4\sin(2x)$.

Comment: find out the $x$ values in $[-\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{2\pi}{3}]$ for which $y'(x)=0$. Then for each $x$ that you find, check $y''(x)$ to see if it is positive or negative. If $y'(x)=0$ and $y''(x)>0$, then $y(x)$ is a minimum. if $y'(x)=0$ and $y''(x)<0$, then $y(x)$ is a maximum

Answer (score 2):

First, find where the derivative is zero ($y'=1+2\cos(2x)=0$).

$$1+2\cos(2x)=0$$
$$2\cos(2x)=-1$$
$$\cos(2x)=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$2x=-\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{2\pi}{3}$$
(within the bounds)
$$x=-\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{3}$$
Checking the second derivative, you can find that $x=-\frac{\pi}{3}$ is local minimum and $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$ is local maximum.

Comment: But in desmos, the min and max x values are +-0.912 respectively, which is not +-pi/3, why is this?

Comment: sorry, my title is wrong - I want it to be x+sin(2x) which explains why desmos was giving me something to different to what I got

Answer (score 0):

Setting first derivative to zero and solving for $x$
$$1 + 2 \cos 2x =0 \to x =\pm \frac {\pi}{3},\pm \frac {2\pi}{3}...$$

So sine sine wave roots are placed with constant period

The second derivative has negative,positive, negative, positive, negative signs alternating signs so that from $ x=0$ you get successively maximum, minimum, maximum, minimum, maximum...extrema after plugging in roots as shown.

[image]